# Under what cases of cone $K$ is $x = \text{proj}_K(x) + \text{proj}_{-K^*}(x)$ possible for all $x$?

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, dual-cone

Here, $K^*$ is the dual cone of $K$:

$K^* = \{x \mid x^Ty \geq 0 \forall y\in K\}.$

The property is true if $K$ is the nonnegative cone or the positive semidefinite cone. Does a more general property apply? Is there an intuitive proof?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer: basically it's all $K$ closed convex cones (woah!), and is a consequence of one of Moreau's theorems.

Here's a link that summarizes it: http://www.convexoptimization.com/wikimization/index.php/Moreau's_decomposition_theorem

The original source is

J.-J. Moreau, Decomposition orthogonale d’un espace hilbertien selon deux cones mutuellement
polaires, Comptes Rendus de l’Acad´emie des Sciences de Paris S´erie A, vol. 255, pp. 238–240, 1962.

Comment: A slightly different viewpoint is that this is a special case of Moreau's identity $x = \text{prox}_{f}(x) + \text{prox}_{f^*}(x)$, which is valid for any closed convex proper function $f$.  In the special case where $K$ is a closed convex cone and $f(x) = I_K(x)$, it turns out $f^* = I_{K^\circ}$, where $K^\circ$ is the polar cone of $K$ defined by $K^\circ = \{ z \mid \langle x, z \rangle \leq 0 \,\forall x \, \in K \}$.  It follows that $\text{prox}_{f}(x) + \text{prox}_{f^*}(x) = \text{proj}_K(x) + \text{proj}_{K^*}(x)$.

Comment: Did not know that about polar cones / dual indicator functions. That is a much shorter proof!